# Testing Angular component with childview using property-binding in svg element

Tags: angular, testing, svg, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular application in which I work on an svg. This svg uses an array of child components that receives some data through property binding.

```
    <svg:g kalk-svg-group *ngFor="let group of groups" [group]="group"></svg:g>
```

This is all very fine whilst running, but when i run my test:

```
it('should create an instance', () => {
const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CanvasComponent);
const component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
expect(component).toBeTruthy();
```

});

i get the following error:

```
1) should create an instance
     Component: Canvas
     Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'group' since it isn't a known property of ':svg:g'. ("ttr.height]="floorplan.height"></svg:image>
    <svg:g kalk-svg-group *ngFor="let group of groups" [ERROR ->][group]="group"></svg:g>
  </svg:g>
</svg>
```

I am well aware that 'group' isn't a property of ':svg:svg' but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: It is not a solution, but you can use a shallow component test ( https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#shallow-component-test ) "NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA". If anyone have a real solution, please let me know.